# Text showing in simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator

I have code this code:

```
let info_centill: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.text = "Connecting people with similar hobbies and interests around the world!"
    tv.font = UIFont(name: "ZonaPro", size: 20)
    tv.textColor = .lightGray
    tv.textAlignment = .center
    tv.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:30,width:0,height:0)
    tv.backgroundColor = .gray

    let fixedWidth = tv.frame.size.width
    tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    let newSize = tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = tv.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    tv.frame = newFrame

    return tv
}()

info_centill.layoutIfNeeded()        
info_centill.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant: 120).isActive = true
info_centill.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
info_centill.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

When I run this code I get this results in simulator:

[image]

But on iPhone I only get the gray background without text. What is the problem and which one should I trust?

Comment: Did you set any constraint?

Comment: @WanhuiQiao yes top right and left,i added them to answer

Comment: Have you used the debug view hierarchy to search for your textField? To Verify if it is at the right position.